# no wifi adapter found in ubuntu 18

Tags: wireless, xubuntu

[image: wifi adapter ubutu]

in my system no wifi adapter found

how I can fix???

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 15
       serial: 70:85:c2:87:12:c3
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:df104000-df104fff memory:df100000-df103fff
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?  eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide which includes links to work out what device you have, and thus can provide us with detail so we can help you if you can't figure it out yourself.

Comment: Know which WiFi adapter driver must be enabled : edit your post, paste the output of  this command `sudo LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 lshw -C network`

Comment: i updated.........

Comment: That command unfortunately can only show network devices already installed, recognized. Please try `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` to identify the hardware.

Comment: lspci -knn | grep Net -A3  this comment showing empty

Comment: No WiFi hardware is shown. Does your WiFi nic be onboard or usb ? If onboard it may have to be enabled from BIOS setings, if usb there might be an issue with usb port activation

Comment: i plugged in the usb 

but not shown

""usb port activation---how i can do..